# PYTSK - Unable to retrieve file type

Tags: python, computer-forensics

I am trying to acquire all files from a windows VHD. 
When calling `.info` or `.info.meta.type` on a file entry it doesn't always work and throws an error. Is there any way to retrieve these files?

```
filesystemObject = pytsk3.FS_Info(imagehandle, offset=(partition.start * metric.block_size))
except:
    print "Partition has no supported file system"
    continue
print "File System Type Dectected ", filesystemObject.info.ftype
directoryObject = filesystemObject.open_dir(path=dirPath)
 for entryObject in directoryObject:
    if (not hasattr(entryObject, "info") or
            not hasattr(entryObject.info, "name") or
            not hasattr(entryObject.info.name, "name") or
            entryObject.info.name.name in [".", ".."]):
        continue

    try:
        f_type = entryObject.info.meta.type

    except:
        print "Cannot retrieve type of", entryObject.info.name.name
        metric.total_files += 1
        metric.failed_files += 1
        continue
```

Traceback:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/paulledwith/PycharmProjects/FYP/Server.py", line 352, in <module>
    directoryRecurse(directoryObject, [])   File "/Users/paulledwith/PycharmProjects/FYP/Server.py", line 185, in directoryRecurse
    directoryRecurse(sub_directory, parentPath)   File "/Users/paulledwith/PycharmProjects/FYP/Server.py", line 185, in directoryRecurse
    directoryRecurse(sub_directory, parentPath)   File "/Users/paulledwith/PycharmProjects/FYP/Server.py", line 185, in directoryRecurse
    directoryRecurse(sub_directory, parentPath)   File "/Users/paulledwith/PycharmProjects/FYP/Server.py", line 172, in directoryRecurse
    print entryObject.info.meta.size AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'
```

This does retrieve about 90% of the files on the 5gb VHD I am working on but 90% is as good as 0.

Comment: we need more info: what is the exception thrown, add a stacktrace

Comment: You don't appear to be showing us the code where the error is thrown: `print entryObject.info.meta.size`